# how to solve given Correlated Subqueries is not supported within case when statement

Tags: presto, correlated-subquery

I have this code where I try to count every distinct user **listed within 30 days prior rolling window**, over the past 40 days.

for example:  on the 12th feb (12/02) I need to count all listed user from 13th jan-12th feb (30 days) then on 11th feb I need to count from 12th jan to 11th feb and so on. I need to do this to a lot of other dates, is there a way to do it in presto? seeing as it does not support correlated subquery and when I try the code below, it returns 
"Given correlated subquery is not supported"

```
WITH
get_date as 
(
  select 
  distinct date_trunc('day',date(uph.last_login)) as dates
  from user_profile_id_history uph 
  where uph.last_login >= date('2020-02-04')-interval '30' day and uph.last_login <= ( date'2020-02-04')
  order by 1 desc
)


select
 get_date.dates,
 (
   case when (dates >= date('2020-02-04')-interval '30' day and dates <= ( date'2020-02-04')) 
   then     
      (
        select
           count(distinct CASE WHEN date_trunc('month',date(up.registration_time)) <= date_trunc('month',uph.last_login) THEN uph.userid END) 
         FROM
             user_profile_id_history uph
         LEFT JOIN
             user_profile up ON uph.userid = up.userid
         where uph.last_login >= dates-interval '30' day and uph.last_login <= dates
       ) end
  ) as mauser       
from get_date
group by 1`
```